# Is there a C++ library to parse qmake project files?

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, project, qmake

I need to parse *.pro files produced by `qmake` to extract sources and headers list from it, for further use in my program.
Of course i can write this code it from scratch - but it can take large time to implement all qmake features support as conditional blocks, pri-files includes, etc.

So, maybe special library for `pro`-files parsing is already exists somewhere?
I've already take a look of qmake and Qt Creator's project plugin source code, but it is uncommented, very large in size and hard to understand - in my opinion. But if will be no other options, i'll be forced to meet closer with them :/

Comment: I have to ask, for what do you need the information from QMake anyway? die Moc'ing should do the things you need for you. But if you want to take control on how things are built you may want to have a look into CMake - there you can define when what is MOCed by QT and linked to where and so on.

Comment: Plain make has the -p argument to print information about a makefile.  Maybe qmake has something similar.

Comment: @Najzero I need only the "SOURCES" and "HEADERS" sections contents, i.e. only the list of project source in current configuration. Those sources will be parsed later by my program (it search some "meta"-info).

Comment: @brianbeuning Unfortunately it haven't such option.

Comment: What about simply opening the .pro files and read them yourself? Find a line that starts with `SOURCES`, read as long as there are lines ending with `\ ` and you're done. Same for `HEADERS` obviously.

Comment: @arne You forgot about conditional blocks, e.g. `unix: SOURCES += unix_only.cpp`, and `include`s of pri-files.
With such things the task became pretty complicated IMO.

Comment: @Axilles Then you could generate `Makefile`s and parse those. Or use `make -p` as brian beuning suggested.

Comment: @arne So i have to run external two external programs, and parse compilcated makefile. That sound not good, especially for cross-platform work ability

Comment: @Axilles Yeah, sounds like it would get ugly. Another suggestion: Have a look at the qmake source code. Depending on the licensing model of your application, you might even be able to copy/link that stuff.

Comment: @arne I'm already check it out. No comments at all in sources :/ So it will be pretty hard to extract parts of source that i need in.

Comment: Maybe at the end of your pro file, use something like message("MAGICSTRING" $$SOURCES) and then pipe the output of qmake to a file and grep for MAGICSTRING which will be followed by the sources

Comment: @Pete Nice idea! but it will be only work than qmake has smth to build. If project was built a few time ago and have no modified files, pro-file will not be parsed, and no message will be produced.

Comment: You could create a file as Pete suggested during `qmake` time and `#include` it into any source file. It would need to be something `C`-ish, but that shouldn't be too hard using `grep` and `sed`. This way, the file list is known to the program and changes if you add/remove files.

Comment: @arne Thanks for the great idea. My chief decide just skip the conditional blocks functionality, so all i need now is simple QRegExp :) although `include`s parser should be implemented, but that is not so hard as conditions.